# How to make a thumbnail created by a function clickable in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make clickable thumbnails in my html code but I cannot figure out how to do it. I know `<a href = "">` won't work. How can I make each thumbnail clickable so that it directs to another page?

Here are the functions I used to get data from the database and to create the thumbnail
`

```
<script>
        $(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/getMovies',
                type: 'GET',
                    success:function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var data = JSON.parse(response);
                    var itemsPerRow = 0;
                    var div = $('<div>').attr('class','row');
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        console.log(data[i].Title);


                        if(itemsPerRow<3){
                            console.log(i);
                            if(i==data.length-1){
                                div.append(CreateThumb(data[i].Id,data[i].Name,data[i].Type,data[i].Copies));
                                $('.well').append(div);
                            }
                            else{
                            div.append(CreateThumb(data[i].Id,data[i].Name,data[i].Type,data[i].Copies));
                            itemsPerRow++;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            $('.well').append(div);
                            div = $('<div>').attr('class','row');
                            div.append(CreateThumb(data[i].Id,data[i].Name,data[i].Type,data[i].Copies));
                            if(i==data.length-1){
                                $('.well').append(div);
                            }
                            itemsPerRow = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    },
                    error:function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        })

        function CreateThumb(id,name,type,copies){
            var mainDiv = $('<div>').attr('class','col-sm-4 col-md-4');
            var thumbNail = $('<div>').attr('class','thumbnail');
            var caption = $('<div>').attr('class','caption');
            var title = $('<h3>').text(name);
            var title = $('<h5>').text(type);
            var title = $('<h4>').text(copies);
            var p = $('<p>');


            caption.append(name);
            caption.append(p);
            caption.append(type);
            thumbNail.append(caption);
            mainDiv.append(thumbNail);
            return mainDiv;

        }
    </script>
```

`.

Comment: You tried `$(document).on("click",".thumbnail",function() {})`

Comment: no i haven't. how can i use it with my code? thank you  @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0):

After you've added the thumbnails use:

```
$(".thumbnail").onclick(function(){
    document.location.href = newUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to clicks with jQuery by using:

```
// Change the selector used below
$('#some-id-here').click(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

There's also another way, using "on". This might be more useful to you, because it also triggers on items added dynamically to the page, which looks to be your case.

```
// Change the selector used below
$('#some-id-here').on('click', 'img', function(){
  // Your code here.
});
```

Also, you can select the document with `$(document)` (instead of `#some-id-here`) to apply it globally on your page, so every `img` tag would trigger this function.